# Unity Light Material "Addative Material"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a 2d plane that is generated thru script and i need it to have a material on it that will work as a light.

What i am doing is having a side scroll game with a generated 2d torch which is the plane, now the environment color and the skybox are pitch black and my 2d torch needs to light up the background that is 3d so far i have gotten almost desirable effects with a particle additive material however the contrast is weak and will not help if the environment is black.

will i need to develop my own shader as i have never done this before id prefer not to or is there a simple material solution that i can use.

i am using unity3.55 free

Answer (score 0):

A particle system won't light anything up.  Your only out-of-the-box solution is a pixel point light.